# Gravity Form hidden field not being sent

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am adding a hidden field in my gravity forms using "gform_pre_render" filter and later on I add a value in it using jQuery.

```
$props = array(
    "id" => "9999",
    "label" => "Hidden value",
    "type" => "hidden",
    "cssClass" => "my_hidden_value
);

$field = GF_Fields::create( $props );
```

The input is added as expected on the form. The only issue I have is that I cannot acces it using "gform_after_submission" action.

All paramteres are in the $entry, except my hidden field.

Anyone had this issue before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this bit from the [gform_pre_render docs](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_render/):

> This filter should be used in conjunction with the gform_pre_validation, gform_pre_submission_filter, and gform_admin_pre_render filters to update the to be able to use those values elsewhere (merge tags in the confirmation and notification, for example).

Hope it helps. :)